# How to scrollup when a div has a programmerly added class

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I'm having problems with my code. When you click on `next`, it does calculations and adds a class `scrollup` (in this example, it's the first three posts). When you click previous, it's suppose to scroll up if a div has a class `.scrollup`. When clicking previous it does not scroll up, even if the item has `.scrollup`.

Example HTML:

```
<button id="prev-item">Previous</button>
<button id="next-item">Next</button>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item first"><div class="current">item 1</div></div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
  <div class="item">item 10</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#next-item").on("click", function () {
    var curr = $('.main .current').parent(); //find .current's parent
    var $children = $('.main').children();
    var firstcal = $children.length;
    var actual = firstcal - 7
    $children.each(function (i) {
        if (i < actual) {
            $(this).addClass('scrollup')
        }
    });
    if (curr.next().length > 0) {
        $('.main').animate({scrollTop: '+=35px'}, 400);
        curr.children('.current').contents().unwrap(); // remove .current
        curr.next().wrapInner('<div class="current"></div>'); // add it to the next element
    }
});

$("#prev-item").on("click", function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("first")) {
        var curr = $('.main .current').parent(); //find .current's parent
        if (curr.next().length > 0) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("scrollup")) {
                $('.main').animate({scrollTop: '-=35px'}, 400);
            }
            curr.children('.current').contents().unwrap(); // remove .current
            curr.prev().wrapInner('<div class="current"></div>'); // add it to the next element
        }
    }
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/openbayou/425Leuq6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**The problem is:** `$(this)` needs to be `curr` in some positions in your code</sup>

- `if ($(this).hasClass("scrollup")){`  .. `$(this)` in your line of code here refer to the `#prev-item` button and the previous button doesn't have `scrollup` class .. the `scrollup` class is for item/parent element of the `current` class element.. so with `$(this)` the if statement will not work .It needs to be `curr.hasClass("scrollup")`
- Also the same thing in `!$(this).hasClass("first")` should be `!curr.hasClass("first")` And use `var curr` line before the `if` statement .. see the code below

```js
$("#next-item").on("click", function(){
  var curr = $('.main .current').parent(); //find .current's parent
  var $children = $('.main').children();
    var firstcal = $children.length;
    var actual = firstcal - 7
    $children.each(function (i) {
      if (i < actual) {
        $(this).addClass('scrollup')
      }
    });
  if (curr.next().length > 0) { 
    $('.main').animate({scrollTop: '+=35px'}, 400);
    curr.children('.current').contents().unwrap(); // remove .current
    curr.next().wrapInner('<div class="current"></div>'); // add it to the next element
  }
});
$("#prev-item").on("click", function(){
  /* HERE >>*/ var curr = $('.main .current').parent(); //find .current's parent
  /* HERE >>*/if (!curr.hasClass("first")) {
     if (curr.next().length > 0) { 
      /* HERE >>*/ if (curr.hasClass("scrollup")){
        $('.main').animate({scrollTop: '-=35px'}, 400);
      }
      curr.children('.current').contents().unwrap(); // remove .current
      curr.prev().wrapInner('<div class="current"></div>'); // add it to the next element
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.current { color: red; }
.item { padding: 7px; }
.main { height: 265px; overflow: auto; }
.scrollup { border-left: 5px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="prev-item">Previous</button>
<button id="next-item">Next</button>
<div class="main">
  <div class="item first"><div class="current">item 1</div></div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
  <div class="item">item 10</div>
</div>
```

<sup>Looking for `/* HERE >>*/` commented in the code to know which lines changed</sup>

Comment: You're totally welcome @GregorySchultz .. Have a great day :-)